# Elasticsearch Template query with json fromat as input param is failing to parse in node js when trying to call elasticsearch client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

We have created a elatic search template that accepts json string as input, when we try to pass input from request param(as json) which is in json, actual call is failing as the input json is converting to string before passing to ES. Anybody had this issue please help.

Actual input:

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "main": "mainType",
      "sub": "subType"
    },
    {
      "main": "mainType1",
      "sub": "subType1"
    }
  ]
}
```

which is converting into

```
{"types":"[{"main":"mainType","sub":"subType"},{"main":"mainType1","sub":"subType1"}]"}



Node Js Client to ES:
elasticClientReq.write(options.postdata);
```

Comment: Please also show your node.js client code

Comment: @Val, i have added node js code. Pls check

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not more clear... Help us help you!!

Comment: let me put in this way, we have a complex json object that needs to passed to server, but inner json object values are automatically converting as "{...}" i don't want these double quotes. hope this is clear.

Comment: That part was already clear, but without seeing how you do it in your code, I'm afraid people won't be able to help you. The single line you added is not sufficient.

Comment: The input from the client is probably not parsed correctly. Are you using parsing middleware like body-parser? How are you passing the data, using POST or GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for support. 
As suggested by  @Vsevolod Goloviznin above in comments i have verified my code and i have used

> JSON.parse(inputrequestparam)

issue got resolved.